# Java Scanner - Using conditions in scanner to check token type and splitting alphanumerals

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, alphanumeric

I am trying to split two lines of strings inputted into the scanner as one big string, back into two separate strings (as shown with my below example and expected output).

**Pseudo Code-ish Code**

```
Scanner s = new Scanner("Fred: 18Bob D: 20").useDelimiter(":") //delimiter is probably pointless here
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
while (s.hasNext()) {
    String str = "";
    if (//check if next token is str) {
        str = str + s.next();
    }
    if (//check if next token is :) {
        //before the : will always be a name of arbitary token length (such as Fred, 
//and Bob D), I also need to split "name: int" to "name : int" to achieve this
        str = str + ": " + s.next();
    }
    if (//check if next token is alphanumeral) {
        //split the alphanumeral then add the int to str then the character
        str = str + s.next() + "\n" + s.next() //of course this won't work 
//since s.next(will go onto the letter 'D')
    }
    else {
        //more code if needed otherwise make the above if statement an else
    }
    list.add(str);
}
System.out.println(list);
```

**Expected Output**

```
Fred: 18
Bob D: 20
```

I just can't figure out how I can achieve this. If any pointers towards achieving this can be given, I would be more than thankful.

Also, a quick question. What's the difference between `\n` and `line.separator` and when should I use each one? From the simple examples I've seen in my class codes, `line.separator` has been used to separate items in a `List<String>` so that's the only experience I have with that.

Comment: Newline separator chars differ based on your operating system. There the JVM has that system property line separator to give you that char(s) you need for the OS you are running on.

Comment: For the conditions in `if`, 1. Check using `if(<string variable>.isEmpty())` 2. `if(<string variable>.equals(":"))` 3. use regular expression to check for alphanumerals `if(<string variable>.matches("[A-Za-z0-9]"))`

Comment: @kiner_shah Would you be able to explain in a bit more detail what you mean by `<string variable>`? I don't understand why you would check if string is empty. Also for 2, since a word directly precedes the `:`, how would I separate that? For 3, I'm assuming this checks the point in which the alphanumeral changes from a letter to an int and separates at the point?

Comment: @Yuxie, 1. You are checking if next token is `str`, which in the previous line has nothing i.e. is empty, 2. If you wanna separate the string using `:`, then use `split()` function with `:` as delimiter, and `<string variable>` means whatever the variable you are using to denote the token. I don't know what you are trying to do in (3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below snippet for your purpose :

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
String str="";
while(s.hasNext()){
    if(s.hasNextInt()){
        str+=s.nextInt()+" ";                                   
    }
    else {                          
        String tmpData = s.next();
        String pattern = ".*?(\\d+).*";
        if(tmpData.matches(pattern)){
            String firstNumber = tmpData.replaceFirst(".*?(\\d+).*", "$1");         
            str+=firstNumber;
            list.add(str);
            str="";
            str+=tmpData.replace(firstNumber, "")+" ";                                                  
        }else{
            str+=tmpData;
        }               
    }           
}
list.add(str);
System.out.println(list);
```

Comment: @Nishesh_Pratap would you be able to explain what `int i` achieves and the purpose of `".*?(\\d+).*", "$1"`? Also, I tried playing around with your code and have noticed that adding a new `name: int` to the existing string seems to not affect the newly added one.

Comment: i is for just for altering the logic, as the second string returned by next() will have both number and name part, so i have to handle it differently. I have used regex ".*?(\\d+).*", "$1" for extracting numerical part. For newly added name: int combination i have made some changes to the logic and updated the answer

Comment: @Nishesh_Pratap thanks for the update! Sorry for bothering you so much but I have 2 more questions (hopefully my last!). 1. Is there a way to 'select' just "Fred" and "D" (so the 2 words before the : ). 2. If the string was expanded to `Fred: 18 19`, is there a way to check if the 3rd token is also an int? So something like `if(s.hasNextInt().hasNextInt())`.

Comment: Use ":" as delimiter and then in loop you can replace integer part with blank. "while(s.hasNext()){
   String tmpData = s.next();
   String firstNumber = tmpData.replaceAll("[0-9]", "").trim();        
  }"